# Delete leading zeros from vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, trim

Can I trim the leading zeros in vectors [0 0 0 2 8 12] , [0 1 8 0 3 0] , [0 0 0 0 25 0] off so to get [2 8 12] , [1 8 0 3 0] , [25 0] with the same function?
Is there a way to do it without using a `while` loop? (Or any other kind of loop?)

I intend to turn the vector into a string, such as '2h 8m 12s', '1mo 8d 0h 3m 0s', '25m 0s', if that will open any doors.

Comment: `v =  [0 0 0 2 8 12]; result = v(find(v,1):end)` ? Or, if you're feeling fancy, `result = v(logical(cumsum((logical(v)))));`

Comment: Why not write the string conversion algorithm in such a way that the trimming is unnecessary? That seems like it could be an easier algorithm to write than having to format the outputs based on the length of the input vector

Comment: What about creating a `datetime` object, and then convert it to a string with `datestr()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionend by @Luis Mendo find() will do the trick.

```
a=[0 0 0 2 8 12];
b=[0 1 8 0 3 0];
c=[0 0 0 0 25 0];

a_short = a(find(a>0,1):end);
b_short = b(find(b>0,1):end);
c_short = b(find(c>0,1):end);
```

The ">0" part in find() is not necessary, but i feel like it helps in regards to readability

Comment: The `>0` part may actually be harmful if the vector has negative elements. It should be `~=0` (or leave it out)